# "NoneType" object is not iterable in Impala query

Tags: hive, impala

I am query to one of the tables using hive and then impala, environment is same, table is same. However, with impala when I try to query count(*) or count(*) with group by it throws below error:

**NoneType Object is not iterable**

SQL:

**Select count(*), mycolumnname from mytablename group by mycolumnname order by mycolumnname desc;**

**Note:** Here datatype of mycolumnname is Date and it is partitioned

However, this works with hive. One more thing, when I select few rows using limit with impala it gives me the result.

Comment: you need to add the SQL, and table definition to answer this qn.

Comment: @KoushikRoy question is updated